# NotFoundHttpException in laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I got this exception for this route: http://localhost:8000/ and other route that I wrote in routes.php file and when I wrote

> php artisan route:list

I got this message

> Your application doesn't have any routes.

I didn't change anything in my code and it worked successfully.I searched about it but I couldn't find an exact answer why this problem happened.
this is routes.php

```
    <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/


Route::get('/', function () {
    $name = ['saba','safavi'];
    return view('welcome'/*,compact('name')*/);
});
Route::get('/sabasafavi', function () {
    return "Salam saba safavi";
});
Route::get('/contact-us', function () {
    return view("contact-us");
});
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::get('/user/{id}',function ($id){
    return "hello user : ".$id;
})/*->where(['id'=>'[0-5]+'])*/;
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::get('/user/{name}/comment/{number}',function ($name,$number){
    $comment = "Hello ".$name." this is your comment</br> number : ".$number;
    return $comment;
});
/*Route::post('/send',function (){
   return "OK information saved successfully";
});*/
```

Comment: share web.php file with us ?

Comment: Show your `routes.php`

Comment: which version of laravel 5?

Comment: Laravel Framework version 5.1.46 (LTS)

Comment: any reason why you use old version for new project?

Comment: no reason I just followed a tutorial website

Comment: @sabasafavi I dont know why you use old version of laravel but try ```php artisan route:clear``` to clear cache and let me know if you use laravel5learning

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your `web.php` is being loaded on R`outeServiceProvider.php`

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}
```

or it might be that your old empty web.php it has been cached since you have cache enabled so do : `php artisan route:clear`  then run `php artisan route:list`

Comment: there is no web.php in laravel 5.1

Comment: @Mohammadb didn't see what ver. he is using, but still pretty much the same he can check that on routes.php file.

Comment: I check the map function and routes.php is being loaded and I had tried php artisan route:clear, and list before

Comment: check your xampp/ mamp or whatever you are using to see if you are loading current project. And check the file routes.php if its in the right dir

Answer (score 0):

this problem is because of renaming your Laravel applications.

If you are using an IDE like PHPStorm or sublime do a full search (find in files) (Edit->Find->Find in Path) of `laravel5learning` across all files in your project directory and all sub-directories and then change it to `App`

then run `php artisan route:list`

Comment: but I didn't rename my Laravel application

Comment: @sabasafavi what is the namespace  in you controller or code classes that you create?

Comment: I don't write extra class or controller in the project just add some new route

Comment: @sabasafavi it doesnt matter chech exist controller to know what is the namespace

Comment: in app/Http/Controllers/contrller.php -->namespace App\Http\Controllers;

Comment: @sabasafavi its default controller , run ```php artisan make:controller FrontController``` for example and check it

Comment: the namespace is same in FrontController class that is been created

Comment: @sabasafavi my last suggestion is that try these commands : ```php artisan clear-compiled ``` ,```composer dump-autoload```,```php artisan optimize```,```php artisan config:clear``` and check again

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
php artisan serve
```

this command and this will give you something like this http://127.0.0.1:8000. So that in localhost you just add this and then your route like -

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

here'/' is your default route i used/
hope will work for you

Comment: Thank you but I tried it before. I decided to make a new project with a new version of Laravel it worked. I didn't know what the hell with the previous project